# Wordpress SQL for list in meta_value

Tags: sql, wordpress

I am trying to write a SQL query, the can be used in a join, where the column I am using for the join, has a list of ID's and not just a single one.

My use case is as follows.

I have a table with a mailing_list_id, for which I ma trying to find the post_id of the post it has been assigned to.

The problem is, the field with the mailing_list_id is in a list as such:

`a:27:{i:0;s:2:"26";i:1;s:2:"28";i:2;s:2:"30";i:3;s:2:"32";i:4;s:2:"34";i:5;s:2:"36";i:6;s:2:"38";i:7;s:2:"40";i:8;s:2:"42";i:9;s:2:"46";i:10;s:2:"50";i:11;s:2:"51";i:12;s:2:"52";i:13;s:2:"55";i:14;s:2:"57";i:15;s:2:"58";i:16;s:2:"59";i:17;s:2:"60";i:18;s:2:"64";i:19;s:2:"65";i:20;s:2:"67";i:21;s:2:"68";i:22;s:2:"69";i:23;s:2:"70";i:24;s:2:"78";i:25;s:2:"80";i:26;s:2:"85";}`

Hence I want to join on this table, where this field contain the mailing_list_id I am looking for. Let us say mailing_list_id is 50 (which is in the list).

How would I go about this?

My query so far:

```
SELECT wp_mailster_fa_details.`username`,
       wp_mailster_fa_details.`mailing_list`
    

    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta
    ON wp_postmeta.`meta_value` LIKE wp_mailster_fa_details.`mailing_list`
    
FROM wp_mailster_fa_details
    WHERE username = 'abc'
```

Currently, I am getting no records returned.

Thank you for you help in advance!

Comment: Why are you using sql to  query the database directly? It’s not recommended in WP or any system that gives you an API  to do it. Why not use Wordpress functions that are meant for getting information from the db - they are there to make it easier for you than trying to join the tables yourself!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, however the problem is, I am trying to build a custom report using a plugin which only allows SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

Since the format of `mailing_list_id` is in a `serialized` format, you will not be able to do this in Mysql alone.

You would need to use [unserialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) in PHP to read your table, and restructure or manipulate the field with PHP, then [serialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) it back to the above state.

OR

you could simply (in Mysql) search for the string `"50"` within this field/record, which is a hacky workaround...